# How to update to spyder‑kernels=2.2?

Tags: python, qt, spyder

Recently I started using Spyder for my python programming. One of the Code required QT version greater than 5.12 so I installed standalone version of Spyder. To install additional packages I am using Anaconda. Despite of creating virtual environment I am not able to use Spyder as kernel throws error. " The Python environment or installation whose interpreter is located at
/Users/ugowda/opt/anaconda3/bin/python
doesn't have the spyder‑kernels module or the right version of it installed (>= 2.2.1 and < 2.3.0). Without this module is not possible for Spyder to create a console for you.

You can install it by activating your environment (if necessary) and then running in a system terminal:
conda install spyder‑kernels=2.2
or
pip install spyder‑kernels==2.2.*"

Tried several online suggestions,didn't work. Did anyone face similar problem ? Do anyone has solution ?

Answer (score 1):

I used this command after I activated my env:

```
pip install spyder-kernels==2.2.1
```